# how to know smtp server name of my ISP?

Tags: php, email

I want to send a mail from localhost. I am using XAMPP to develop my php app.I found in google that I have to modify `php.ini` file, `localhost must be replaced by server name of  my ISP`.Whats that???

```
[mail function]
```

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISP is short for [Internet Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISP).

Regarding SMTP, I doubt that they will let you set up your own SMTP on localhost.

If you use a Mail Client like Outlook you have provided an SMTP Address for Sending mail, use the same one in your php.ini and you will be able to send mails.

Otherwise, call your Internet Service Provider and ask them what the address to their SMTP server is.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can ran your own smt server ie. you can ran your Windows IIS with smtp server. Try Google how to set up your smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MailEnable free version and configure this correctly with your ISP DNSs.
If your ISP allows port 25, you should be able to send out emails with this setup.